# CSS Linear-gradient formatting issue accross different browsers

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I've been tasked with applying a theme to a website and the theme I have been given has some strange syntax in the `css` file that I haven't encountered before.

The theme is working fine on Firefox and Chrome but on IE is where I have experienced problems. In particularly with a `div` bar that lies horizontally accross the web page becoming almost transparent with some objects seen through it. This doesn't happen on Firefox or IE though.

When I investigated the page source I found the div had the following styling options. `-moz-linear-gradient` and `-webkit-gradient` so I initially thought that wsa the problem.

```
#aqua_bar_bottom {
        position:fixed;
        bottom:0; right:0; left:0;
        height:33px;
        overflow:hidden;
        background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #CBCBCB, #A7A7A7);
        background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom,
            from(#CBCBCB),
            to(#A7A7A7)
        );
        border-top:1px solid #515151;
        z-index:102;
}
```

I discovered through http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp that these background values are assigned to Firefox and Chrome and figured that as the IE browser I'm using should be liner-gradient compatible I added the following line `background:linear-gradient(top, #CBCBCB, #A7A7A7);`.

```
#aqua_bar_bottom {
        position:fixed;
        bottom:0; right:0; left:0;
        height:33px;
        overflow:hidden;
        background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #CBCBCB, #A7A7A7);
        background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom,
            from(#CBCBCB),
            to(#A7A7A7)
        );
        background:linear-gradient(top, #CBCBCB, #A7A7A7);
        border-top:1px solid #515151;
        z-index:102;
}
```

This has not resolved the issue though, it seems the IE web page has been unaffected by these changes.

Comment: Try generating from gradient generator online

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the property from `background` to `background-image` and the `top` argument to 'to-bottom' did the trick

```
background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom, #CBCBCB 0%, #A7A7A7 100%);
```

Answer (score 1):

You want:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#cbcbcb', endColorstr='#a7a7a7',GradientType=0 );
```

This works for IE6-9.

10+ should recognize:

```
background: linear-gradient(top, #cbcbcb 0%,#a7a7a7 100%);
```