# CSS3 linear-gradient issues with different browsers

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I'm trying to add an transparent linear-gradient to a div, and making it work in different browsers seems to be not so easy.

```
background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(left center , $secondary-color, rgba(255, 82, 66, 0) 52%);
background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(left center , $secondary-color, rgba(255, 82, 66, 0) 52%);
background-image:-o-linear-gradient(left center , $secondary-color, rgba(255, 82, 66, 0) 52%);
background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(left center , $secondary-color, rgba(255, 82, 66, 0) 52%);
background-image: linear-gradient(left center , $secondary-color, rgba(255, 82, 66, 0) 52%);
```

This doesn't work in any browser at all. If I remove all lines **except** the `-moz-linear-gradient`, it works in Firefox. How come?

The error message is "*Invalid property value*". But as it works with only the `-moz-` vendor presented, I think the values should be good?

Comment: Because you aren't using the correct syntax (atleast definitely not for the standard `linear-gradient`).

Comment: According to [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp): linear-gradient(left top, red, yellow) - is the the opacity at the end that is the problem?

Comment: You can (and should) drop most of these prefixes anyway: http://caniuse.com/#search=gradient

Comment: @BTB: No, the opacity is not a problem. The problem is most likely because of your incorrect `linear-gradient` syntax (not the prefixed ones). If you see in the that link for the standard property, it would only have ` to side [side]` syntax and not just a `side [side]` syntax.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS Linear-gradient formatting issue accross different browsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34337760/css-linear-gradient-formatting-issue-accross-different-browsers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They don't work because everything other than your `-moz-linear-gradient` syntax is incorrect. The correct syntax for the others is provided in the below snippet for your reference. (*Replace the red with your $secondary-color.*)

- The [`-webkit-linear-gradient`](https://webkit.org/blog/1424/css3-gradients/) syntax is supporting the two side syntax but looks like `center` is not an allowed value. So, for example, `left top` or `left bottom` as first parameter will result in a diagonal gradient but `left center` produces no output.
- The standard [`linear-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient) property doesn't use `side side` as first parameter. It uses `to [side] [side]` as the first parameter. So, a diagonal gradient to would be like `to left top` or `to left bottom` whereas a horizontal gradient would be `to left` or `to right`.

Even as per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient), the `center` is not a valid value for the `-moz-linear-gradient` function and so its a surprise that Firefox is able to work with that value. Maybe, it just ignores the invalid value whereas the other browsers ignore the whole property + value.

> -moz-linear-gradient([ **[ [top | bottom] || [left | right] ]**,]? <color-stop>[, <color-stop>]+);

```css
body{
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, red, rgba(255, 82, 66, 0) 52%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left center, red, rgba(255, 82, 66, 0) 52%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, red, rgba(255, 82, 66, 0) 52%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red, rgba(255, 82, 66, 0) 52%);
}
```

Comment: All right! I wasn't aware of these differences. Thank you very much, Harry :-)

Comment: And just in case you are wondering why I left the `center` in the other prefixed versions (or the extra `[side]` in the standard version), it is because this is just a plain horizontal gradient and not a digonal one. So, the other side value is not needed.

Comment: @BTB: I've added some more information that I could find on the web. Have a look and see if it helps you further understand the problem :)